# Getting framework(MLVision/MLVisionTextModel) not found issue when Integration firebase SDKs without using Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-mlkit

I am working on integration firebase ML vision kit without using the cocoa pods:

I am getting below error when adding SDK frameworks(MLVision and MLVisionTextModel) in app :

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Point 1:**

My steps as I followed in app to integrate these SDK's framework :

A.  Downloaded firebase SDK 5.20.2.

B.  Followed the steps as defined inside the Readme.md file.

First, I added all framework from 'Analytics' directory into project navigator pane and do same thing for Firebase.h file. Added the -ObjC flag to "Other Linker Settings In AppDelegate.m , I add #import "Firebase.h" and [FIRApp configure];.

**Project build successfully without any error.**

C. **Getting issue** : For text recognition, I added MLVision and MLVisionTextModel in app as defined the step 5 in Readme.md for require framework and resource.

**When I build this project I am getting below error in app:**

I am getting below error as

`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_iostream()", referenced from: l59875 in TextDetector "typeinfo for std::__1::basic_iostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >", referenced from: l59875 in TextDetector
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

**Point 2: Getting issue**

Sometimes I was trying same thing adding SDK's framework by 'Link Binaries With Libraries' in Build Phases for Analytics, MLVision and MLVisionTextModel.

I was getting below error as

`ld: framework not found FirebaseMLVisionTextModel 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

**Note:** The framework FirebaseMLVisionTextModel doesn't have FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.h file. It doesn't exist header folder which is missing in FirebaseMLVisionTextModel framework: 
I am getting same issue for TextDetector.framework which doesn't have any header folder.

Firebase.h : Deceleration file in Firebase.h which is missing in framework:

```
#if __has_include(<FirebaseMLVisionTextModel/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.h>)
#import <FirebaseMLVisionTextModel/FirebaseMLVisionTextModel.h>
#endif
```

- Xcode version: 10.1
- Firebase SDK version: 5.20.2
- Firebase Component: ML Kit (text recognition)
- Component version:

Pls suggest how do I fix this problem.

How do I use `FirebaseMLVisionTextModel` and `TextDetector` framework that doesn't have any header , these frameworks have only exec file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2843:

The system C++ libraries are not being linked. That can happen with an incorrect Xcode module cache. Do `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` to reset. If that doesn't work, add libc++ to the Link Binary With Libraries Build Phase:

[image]

Comment: I am getting other issue in different app. I have posted at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771201/getting-frameworksgooglemobilevision-firebasemlcommon-issue-when-integrate-fir

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I am getting other issue in different app. I have posted at 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55771201/getting-frameworksgooglemobilevision-firebasemlcommon-issue-when-integrate-fir

Any help is appreciated. Thanks