# Getting frameworks(GoogleMobileVision/FirebaseMLCommon) issue when integrate firebase SDK without using Cocoa pods

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-mlkit, xcode10.1

Getting below error when adding firebase SDK in app:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_LAContext", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in FirebaseMLCommon(MDMPasscodeCache_ac345e06741a76a3aefe61adde149175.o)
>
> objc-class-ref in GoogleMobileVision
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Xcode version: 10.1
Firebase SDK version: 5.20.2
Firebase Component: ML Kit (text recognition)
Component version:

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Similar answer as https://stackoverflow.com/a/55750927/556617 - Add LocalAuthentication.framework instead of libc++ to the `Link Binary with Libraries` Build Phase.

Comment: Great shot, this solve the current migration to Xcode 11.2

Answer (score -1):

Why don't u install **CocoaPods**?

```
pod setup
```

as a sequence,

```
pod repo update
```

RefURL: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/INSTALLATION.md#cocoapods

Comment: Because CocoaPods is evil